# Using For...Of loop to change an array

Tags: javascript

Looking for a resource to explain why when I run the below code, my original array doesn't change.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4];
for(let val of arr){
  val = val * 2;
  console.log(val);
}
console.log(arr);
```

I am learning about for...in and for...of loops and not sure why my console.log(arr) doesn't print out [2,4,6,8].

Comment: because you are changing `val` not anything in the array itself

Comment: You are not setting up new value back to array. That's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the the identifier `val` is being overwritten. With another integer and val is just a temp variable invoked each iteration of the loop. If you used an object, and did not reassign the variable, your values would remain intact

```
// Object values
var x = [{z:1},{z:2}]
for(let y of x){
    // No reassignment
    y.z=3;
}
console.log(x); //[{"z":3},{"z":3}]
```

If you want to modify an array of simple types in place, you can do something like:

```
var q = [5,6,7];
for( i in q){
    q[i] = q[i] * 2;
}
console.log(q); //[10, 12, 14]
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying and not inserting in back.

Better you use `for each` this case. So that you'll be able to modify the array. Using `of` make things complicated.

```js
arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.forEach(function(part, index, array) {
   array[index] = array[index]*2;
   });
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `for..in` shouldnt be used with array iterations. It will loop prototype chain as well causing unexpected results.

Comment: @sabithpocker Yeah true. However it won't break in this specific case. Just to make it 100% correct, used for each.

Comment: Cool man, answered a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091849/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript-using-a-for-in-loop/48092122#48092122) last day so this sticked on in my mind.

Comment: @sabithpocker You need to say "so this _stuck_ on my mind."

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop, which enables you to make the assignments "stick" in the original array.

```js
arr = [1,2,3,4];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    arr[i] = 2*arr[i];
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

The issue with what you were originally doing is that `val` is just a variable with no real connection to the underlying array.  Hence, doubling `val` has no effect on the array itself.

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate the time to help with my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `forEach` too, which runs a particular function for every value in the array.

```js
arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.forEach((d, i, arr) => arr[i]*=2);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me!